# how to add a timestamp to a file using the last modified date instead of current date

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a way to add the last modified timestamp to a file name? I'm trying to backup files older than 10 days and I'm trying to smack the last modified date to the files the script finds:

```
find /users/tnea01/logfile* -mtime +10 -type f -exec sh -c \ 'tar -czvPf /users/tnea01/logfile_archive/$(basename $0)_$(date +%F).tar.gz $0' {} \;
```

instead of using date +%F I wanted to use the modified date and not the current.

Thanks you

Comment: You can use `stat -c %y` to get the modification time of a file.

Comment: `touch -d "date string"` to use `"date string"` instead of current time, or `-t "time stamp"` as well.

Comment: _GNU_ `date` (on LInux) supports `-r/--reference filename` so: `$(date -r {} +%F)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! dave_Thompson_085 I used your solution which works perfectly $(date -r {} +%F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do in this case is use the `-r` for date. So you can:

```
date -r <filename>
```

will return a date like: `Tue Jul 26 14:02:26 PDT 2016`

If you can also use the `%F` or `%D` after the filename as you were doing:

```
date -r <filename> +%F
```

will return just the `yyyy-mm-dd` like `2016-07-26`

Comment: Thank you RBenito! -r is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @RBenito Thank you